# ERROR in Module not found: Error: Package path . is not exported from package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Firebase.js:

```
import firebase from "firebase";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: <<API_KEY>>,
    authDomain: "fir-42683.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "fir-42683",
    storageBucket: "fir-42683.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "950284829228",
    appId: "1:950284829228:web:f9e6862d17650cfca38789",
    measurementId: "G-VWT1P7ES8S"
  };
 
  export const db = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```

App.js

```
import  {db }  from './Firebase'
```

I wrote just a simple code for read data from firebase. but now, iam stuck on this error, what will i do.

```
ERROR in ./src/Firebase.js 3:0-32 Module not found: Error: Package path . is not exported from package D:\BROCAMP\Week 15\olx\node_modules\firebase (see exports field in D:\BROCAMP\Week 15\olx\node_modules\firebase\package.json)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `const db = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)`

You missed one step, this is actually `const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)`

Consider this hook which can get your `db`:

**useGetFirestore.ts**

```
import { getApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore, Firestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const useGetFirestore = (): Firestore => {
  const app = getApp();
  return getFirestore(app);
};

export default useGetFirestore;
```

The code you are calling `db` is actually `app` and that code just needs to run at the top of your app before anything:

`const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);`

Sometimes you only need this:

`initializeApp(firebaseConfig);`